# ElementNotInteractableException error message

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

I have been working on some RobotFramework stuff and I am having an issue. I am trying to access ta set of links that appear when the settings menu is pressed. I assume that we would need to do some window switching but am having trouble with it as I am pretty new to RF and Python. Would anyone be able to point in the direction of some assistance? I have tried using the documentation but I just cant seem to get it.

Thank you

p.s this is some code where I seem to be getting the issue

```
Go to               http://localhost/index.php?redirect=0
Click Element       id:quickaccess-popover-content
Click Element       //*[@id="quickaccess-popover content"]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a
```

Comment: This is not really restricted to robot but related with selenium. It could be multiple things, like the links open in a new window and you need to switch window, it opens inside a iframe and you need to "enter" the frame before being able to interact with the elements. Or as simple as you need to wait for the elements to be shown in screen before interacting with them (frameworks that use selenium usually have a "wait for element visible" or similar).

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment and sorry for the delay in replying, I managed to get it using a different method of access and was pretty basic from then on. I must go back and try to get it in the ways you mentioned just for future reference. Thanks again !